# Get xml data and insert into database

Tags: mysql, xml, insert

How can i insert XML data into my table?

Here is my `XML` data:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [songitem] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [song] => Elona
                            [album] => AL-F-001
                            [path] => link1
                            [calen] => 278
                            [dl] => d1
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [song] => Evis
                            [album] => AL-F-002
                            [path] => link2
                            [calen] => 279
                            [dl] => d2
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [song] => Kozeta
                            [album] => AL-F-003
                            [path] => link3
                            [calen] => 280
                            [dl] => d3
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

want to get song, album,path etc.. and insert into table.

Comment: What is the table structure that you are trying to insert into?  Have you tried writing a query to do it?  If you have, can you post it?

Comment: table columns are same as song,album.. etc..

Comment: Use [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) to transform raw file into a cleaner format for MySQL's [LOAD XML](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) query. Please post actual XML.

Comment: this is the actual XML